# Shift key stopped working

Tags: keyboard

I am using Elementary os 5.1.7. Both my shift keys are not working. Previously I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and the keys were working absolutely fine.

Comment: your keyboard problem , change your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you've already tried but if it's not your keyboard hardware that's the problem:

1. Check that your keyboard layout matches your keyboard *(Keyboard > Layout)*
2. Check to see that something happens when you use `xev | awk /keysym/'{sub(/\)\,/,"", $7); print $7}'`  in a console window and press Shift a bunch.

If you do get a result with `xev` Then your key is definitely working, and you likely just need to change your keyboard layout/mapping. If not, you may need to look at getting a new keyboard.

Good luck, Col

Comment: Thank you. I checked what you suggested sadly it didn't work. It seems like both the shift keys failed working somehow.

Comment: I mapped caps lock to shift key for time being `xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L"` https://askubuntu.com/questions/371394/how-to-remap-caps-lock-key-to-shift-left-key